# How to validate a requirement/dependency in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have the following setup:

```
/-
  .project-name
  Makefile
  ...
```

The content of `.project-name` is `dummy`

```
cat .project-name
dummy
```

One of the targets of the `Makefile` is `set_project_name` which (as its name suggests) changes (using `sed`) the name of the project all around the directory and adjusting some paths too

```
set_project_name: 
    @ag [dD]ummy -l0 | xargs -0 sed -i  "s/[dD]ummy/${PROJECT_NAME}/g"
    ## Renombrar la carpeta del proyecto
    @[[ -d dummy ]] && mv dummy/pipelines/dummy.py dummy/pipelines/$(PROJECT_NAME).py
    @[[ -d dummy ]] && mv dummy $(PROJECT_NAME)
```

also in the `Makefile` the variable `PROJECT_NAME` is just

```
   PROJECT_NAME := `cat .project-name`
```

I want to validate that the user of this changed the content of `.project-name` before executing anything in the  `Makefile`

I tried using

```
TEST_PROJECT_NAME_2 := [[ 'dummy' == $(cat .project-name) ]] && $(error "ERROR: The name of the project can not be 'dummy', please use another name")
```

But is not working, it executes, but always throws the error.

I tried also with `ifeq` at the top of the `Makefile` but that is not executing neither. What I am doing wrong? Also, Is this the best approach for doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language `make` uses is not the same that the shell uses. Things like

```
PROJECT_NAME := `cat .project-name`
```

will not make PROJECT_NAME the contents of the .project-name file (it will assign the string "`cat .project-name`". Likewise,

```
TEST_PROJECT_NAME_2 := [[ 'dummy' == $(cat .project-name) ]] ...
```

will not do what you think it does. To assign the standard output of a shell command, you need to use `make` syntax such as

```
FOOFILE := $(shell cat foo)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jens I modified as you suggested but the error still persists

    `PROJECT_NAME:=$(shell cat .project-name)` and also


   `TEST_PROJECT_NAME_2 := if [ 'dummy' == ${PROJECT_NAME} ]; then $(error "ERROR: El nombre del proyecto no puede ser 'dummy', por favor utiliza otro nombre"); fi;`

Comment: For the validation part you should use `ifeq`, `ifdef`, `ifndef` etc as stated in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html)